# dynamically create objects in a loop

Tags: loops, object, dynamic, creation

I am a complete newbie to Java programming, I want to dynamically create objects in Java during run time, I have checked the forms and tried some code but nothing really seems to work.

here is my code .. all help is really appreciated :)

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   String carName;
   String carType;
   String engineType;
   int limit;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the number of Cars you want to add - ");
  limit = in.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i <limit; i++){

    Cars cars[i] = new Cars();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of Car Name - ");
    carName = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of Car Type - ");
    carType = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the Engine Type - ");
    engineType = in.nextLine();

    cars[i].setCarName(carName);
    cars[i].setCarType(carType);
    cars[i].setEngineeSize(engineType);
    String a = cars[i].getCarName();
    String b = cars[i].getCarType();
    String c = cars[i].getEngineeSize();
    System.out.println(a,b,c);

  } 
  }
  }
```

---

The cars class looks like this ..

```
    public class Cars{
    public String carName;
    public String carType;
    public String engineeSize;

    public void Cars(){
    System.out.println("The Cars constructor was created ! :-) ");
    }

    public void setCarName(String cn){
    this.carName = cn;
    }

    public void setCarType(String ct){
    this.carType = ct;

    }

    public void setEngineeSize(String es){
    this.engineeSize = es;

    }

    public String getCarName(){
    return this.carName;
    }



    public String getCarType(){
    return this.carType;
    }

    public String getEngineeSize(){
    return this.engineeSize;
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, there are a few errors and unnecessary bits though.

**The Cars Class**

Your Cars class was mostly fine, (though in my opinion `Car` would have made more sense) however your constructor didn't make sense, you had `public void Cars()`, `void` means "this method returns nothing", but you want to return a `Cars` object, meaning your constructor needs to become:

```
public Cars()
{
    System.out.println("The Cars constructor was created ! :-) ");
}
```

**Your Main Class**

You were very close here as well, your primary issue was creating the `cars` array `limit` times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    Cars cars[i] = new Cars();
    //Other code
}
```

The array needs to be made outside the `for` loop.

Here is the revised `Main` class in full, the comments should explain fairly well what I did and why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){
    //The strings here were unnecessary
    int limit;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of Cars you want to add - ");
    limit = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); //nextInt leaves a newLine, this will clear it, it's a little strange, but it makes sense seeing as integers can't have newlines at the end

    //Make an array of Cars, the length of this array is limit
    Cars[] cars = new Cars[limit];

    //Iterate over array cars
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        //Read all the properties into strings
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Car Name - ");
        String carName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of Car Type - ");
        String carType = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the Engine Type - ");
        String engineType = in.nextLine();

        //Set the object at current position to be a new Cars
        cars[i] = new Cars();

        //Adjust the properties of the Cars at this position
        cars[i].setCarName(carName);
        cars[i].setCarType(carType);
        cars[i].setEngineeSize(engineType);

        //We still have the variables from the scanner, so we don;t need to read them from the Cars object
        System.out.println(carName+carType+engineType);
    } 
    in.close(); //We don't need the scanner anymore
   }
}
```

Finished typing this and realized that the question is two years old :)